# Can I use a 16/3 extension cord for a refrigerator?

Tags: electrical, extension

I have an outlet that is dead by the refrigerator.  Can I use an extension cord temporarily and what would be the minimum?   It is a small apartment sized refrigerator.

Comment: How long a run to the next good outlet?

Comment: What is the amperage of the refrigerator?

Comment: I would buy the shortest appliance rated cord that will reach the nearest outlet.   No don't use that 50 or 100 foot orange 16/3 cord from the garage.

Comment: There should be a tag on the back of the fridge or possibly on its cord. This tag should specify its electrical requirements: some combination of amps, volts, and watts. Could you edit your question to include that information?

Answer (score 1):

Wire gauge tables for 16AWG list the maximum carrying current from 4 to 10 amps continuous; for 18AWG, 2 to 5 amps (for under 50-ft lengths, at least).  I think it's unlikely that your fridge draws more than 2 amps under any conditions ( if you have a tag on the unit which lists watts, just divide watts by 120 (voltage) to get amps), so any extension cord you have will be fine.  However, if the fridge has a 3-prong plug, be sure to use a matching 3-wire extension cord for grounding safety.

Comment: Since it is a residual refrigerator simply buy a #12 extension, it will be an overkill but it will come in useful later.